# How to use nuxt build (webpack) extend for transforming specific files from assets directory?

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

I have a static HTML file and I need to replace some values inside it based on the environment I'm deploying. And I cannot use it as a vue page or anything. So I wanted to make it dynamic with the environmental variables. But, as this is not possible to access env variables inside static or assets directory, I wanted to make use of webpack build (`nuxt.config.js` -> `build` -> `extend`) to transform that file during build time before it is copied to the dist directory.

```js
export default {
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    extend(config, ctx) {}
  }
}
```

I've gone through the nuxt docs but was not able to find any reference for that or any example from where I can use my custom logic or extend the existing logic to transform my HTML file.

Can anyone have any example of how I can process any file (mine is HTML) from assets (or static) with the use of the webpack?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What do you want to update in your HTML file? I'm pretty sure you can do that somewhere else without any HTML hack through Webpack.

Comment: I have a page which uses api URL and chrome extension id which is different based on the deployed environment. As this HTML page is in static folder, I've to do multiple commits and maintain separate branches with different details. But merging with keeping things different makes it hard for me.

Comment: Can't you use env variables for that purpose? Also, why do you have it in `static` + `html`?

Comment: in static, I can't access env variables. That is an altogether different page, that is opened in a iframe/webview from the chrome extension. So I can't club it with the website pages

Comment: You could run a serverless function or alike, to generate the HTML on-fly, with your dynamic variables there and serve it when asked. Does it matter to have something **static** or can it be generated from an endpoint?

Comment: I've made an API to get the config dynamic, but at the end the base URL for the API has to be dynamic, that's the only issue left.

Comment: Why don't you reach a non-changing endpoint, ask for the content there and depending from where the HTTP call is made, it is serving you a different endpoint/dynamic stuff. You will have your dynamic thing on the backend rather than trying some ugly hacks on the frontend.

Comment: It is on my backend only, that is the only reason I have to change the baseUrl on that now. All other things are coming from the API now.

Comment: I didn't get your last comment.